# Relation between Normalizers of groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> If $D$ is a cyclic $p$-subgroup of $G$ and $E$ a subgroup of $D$, we have the relationship that the normalizer of $E$ contains that of $D$.

I am not sure how to prove it. I thought $D$ is contained in the normalizer of $E$ But That's all I' ve got. Any hint would be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Hint: subgroups of cyclic groups are characteristic.

Answer (score 1):

For any $g\in N$, consider the inner automorphism $i_g$ of $G$ determined by $g$.

$D$ is invariant under $i_g$ for any $g\in N(D)$.  Thus $i_g|_D\in\operatorname{Aut}D$. That is, $i_g$ restricts to an automorphism of $D$.

But since $D$ is cyclic, $E$ is characteristic in $D$.  Thus $i_g(E)=E$.  That is, $g\in N(E)$.